# serverlessの「cloudwatch log」eventにて複数のlogをトリガーに設定したい

Tags: aws, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

以下の公式のドキュメントを参考に、cloudwatch log をトリガーにイベント発火することはできました。
https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/cloudwatch-log/

webコンソール上では、複数のcloudwatch log のトリガーを設定できるため、同様の事をコードでも実装したく以下のように記述しましたが、ダメでした。

```
      - cloudwatchLog:
          logGroup: '/aws/lambda/hello1'
          filter: '{$.userIdentity.type = Root}'

      - cloudwatchLog:
          logGroup: '/aws/lambda/hello2'
          filter: '{$.userIdentity.type = Root}'
```

似たような形式でいくつか試したのですが、1つのlambdaに対して2つ登録させることが困難です。

現状は、複数のlambda関数を生成し、それぞれに、1つのトリガーを設定することで回避しておりますが、トリガーに設定したいlogの数分だけ、コードの量が肥大化してしまい見通しがかなり悪くなりました。（lambda関数も増大しております）

表題のようなことができるのでしたら、非常に管理が楽になります。

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

このような表記で動きました。
ただし、AWS Lambdaのwebコンソールから確認すると、トリガーが設置されていないように見えるのですが、実際には期待通りに動作していますので、その点注意が必要です。

serverless.yml

```
functions:
  myCloudWatchLog:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - cloudwatchLog: '/aws/lambda/hello1'
      - cloudwatchLog: '/aws/lambda/hello2'
```